# simple way to send addressable RGB signal wirelessly

Tags: rf, led-strip, transmitter

So my electronics knowledge is pretty limited, But I'm hoping there is a simple way to do what I want. Also I'm sorry if this question is answered somewhere else as I'm probably not using the right search terms or something.

I have an addressable RGB LED strip controlled by an Arduino. It has a 4-wire connector. Basically I want the strip to be wireless. Is there a simple RF transmitter and receiver I can buy where all I need to do is connect the TX to the Arduino and the RX to the strip (and a battery)? The distance would only need to be 3 to 6ft. Obviously I retain the ability for the LEDs to be individually addressable and RGB.

Would something like [this](https://www.banggood.com/2_4G-3_3V-Wireless-Module-Transceiver-Long-Distance-Low-Power-Anti-interference-LT8920-ultra-NRF24L01-p-1510902.html?akmClientCountry=CA&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc_organic&utm_medium=cpc_bgcs&gmcCountry=CA&utm_content=minha&utm_content=haosen&utm_campaign=minha-cag-en-mb&utm_campaign=haosen-pla-cag-all-rm-cart-mb-1003&currency=CAD&cur_warehouse=CN&createTmp=1&ID=514814&ad_id=470326699176&gclid=CjwKCAiAr6-ABhAfEiwADO4sfVLHPwq8ev0K--sMaRoD54sXD5u-qf4EbFpeU4HM4vpBIrKTJYRF8RoCk_IQAvD_BwE) work? I'm guessing I'd only need to connect the LEDs to 2 of the pins? since, of the 4 wires, 1 is ground and an other is the 12v input. And I'd need to provide a separate 3.3v for the transceivers. But I wouldn't really know which pins I'd need to connect.

Thanks!

Comment: No, that will not work directly.  This is not a simple problem at all; it's probably going to require some software on both ends especially if you want to update rapidly.  Additionally questions asking for recommendations on what to buy are off topic under site rules.

Comment: thanks for the heads up on the rules! the question is primarily about whether my task is simple or not and brought up the transceivers as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve this. In all scenarios I can think of, you would leave the Arduino (or *an* Arduino, not necessarily the one you have) in control of the RGB lights.

You then transmit some data to the Arduino to tell it what colour to set the LED strip to, and to turn it on or off, or start some other procedure.

The easiest way to do this is probably with the [Arduino IoT Cloud](https://www.arduino.cc/en/IoT/HomePage) and a compatible IoT Arduino board (eg the Arduino Nano 33 IoT). Noting that the Nano IoT is a 3.3v board. Alternately you could use any other IoT board with an IoT breakout board, or my preferred option would be to wait for the new Arduino Nano RP2040 which should be perfect for your use-case.

You could also use a similar board like an ESP32, but they're a little less straightforward to use which, although not really complex, sounds like it might be a little above the level you want at the moment when you're already introducing new skills and technologies.

Comment: While there are a lot of ways this could be done, given the context of the question, I think this is probably the best solution.  There is already an Arduino involved, so programming one is a given.  Not much harder to get one that includes wireless networking and leverage the huge amount of code and hardware already out there for the task.

Comment: While this isn't really the answer I was hoping for. I now know there is no simple plug and play solution for me. Using an Arduino or some other MCU seems to likely be my best bet.

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of project on the net using ESP32 to control these LEDs.

This microcontroller has WiFi, which is pretty useful for wireless control.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use an IR remote control chip to Rx and IR LED to transmit. That ought work as well as other LED remote control.

If you can figure out the protocol for the SPI interfaces involved  and make it transparent in the cheap radio from Banggood in your link , then you may have found a good solution.

Comment: That would only support switching between pre-defined patterns, not actually sending the data for the addressable LEDs if any quantity of them need to be updated regularly.

Comment: That's true, but this is how inexpensive LED Reels are produced with embedded uC on the Reel and inexpensive canned settings selected by remote.

Comment: Yeah there's a pile on products out there that work like that. Unfortunately I need the dynamic output that the Arduino supplies as it needs to read from a sensor and adjust the LEDs accordingly.

Comment: Send the sensor readings and put the light program at the lights

Comment: Regarding your edit: See I was hoping it would be simpler. Since I know the LEDs use an SPI interface and the Radio I referenced does as well then there would be some compatibility there. Hoped it was just a matter of connecting everything properly.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes sending the sensor info might be the easier way to go. I just wanted to keep the Receiving end as absolutely small and low power as possible. I know Arduinos are small, but smaller is better.

Comment: The sensor protocol is unlikely to match the LED bytes but the serial port will work. Just needs an algorithm to be defined.

Comment: @tylermackenzie the power drawn by the LEDs will dwarf that drawn by the computer.  There are plenty of truly tiny MCU's don't mistake the size of an arduino board for the _necessary_ size, there are smaller boards too - a trinket M0 is pretty small, and only half of it really needed.  **Anyway, you aren't going to accomplish this without an MCU-equivalent in the receiver regardless**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I guess you are probably right about the power requirements. And yeah I'm starting to realize, as you said, that there's no dead-simple way to do it. I'll need an MCU and more know-how.

Answer (score 0):

Addressable LED like ws2812 has communication protocol with bitrate 800 Kbit/s. You can not disconnect data line and put some simple RF communication between. It is doable with more complicated transmitter-receiver. They already have special MCU inside. So two MCU may communicate.

Comment: So basically you're saying I need to do a bunch of research and learning because I can't just send that signal over RF without some special microprocessor on each end?

Comment: Yes. There is a lot on-shelf not expensive controllers with Wi-Fi, IR remote, etc.  To do something like that by yourself you need to invest a lot of time and money, probably